# stopImmediatePropagation Not Working with A Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('a[href="/my-url"]').click(function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  var win = window.open('https://newwebsite.com', '_blank');
});
```

I am trying to get a URL to stop opening up on SquareSpace and open a new link, but with the limitations I can only do so using javascript.
The code will open up the new window - but it will not stop the old url from also opening up in the current tab.

Comment: Maybe the link is opened via another click event? You could try clearing all click events before you add this handler. `.off()` would work if it was added as a generic handler to the element via jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href="/my-url"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  var win = window.open('https://newwebsite.com', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: hmmm... this works, but if you click another link in the website and go back and click the link again it opens up /my-url.

Comment: Then you need to assign an id or a class to the a so that the the js function only affects it.  eg <a href="/my-url" class"to-page">*****</a> and then in js $('a.to-page').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  var win = window.open('https://newwebsite.com', '_blank');
});

Comment: and remember to return false after var win

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault` instead:

```
$('a[href="/my-url"]').click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var win = window.open('https://newwebsite.com', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: tried that first still opens /my-url along with the new tab

Comment: Do you *need* the `/my-url` - can't you just do `#`?

Comment: the way the template works u need to provide a slug for the image